# Order of operations for @bindable

Tags: aurelia

If I have a child control (or grandchild in this case) that looks like this:

```
<my-control region-id.two-way="location.regionId"></my-control>
```

When can I expect `regionId` to be available? The docs sound like bind and then attached happens so shouldn't `regionId` be set prior to attached happening?

I have added some logging to the `bind`, `attached`, and `regionIdChanged` events and looking at the console, I see

```
bind
attached
regionIdChange to null from undefined (default value in a dropdown)
regionIdChange to 1 from null (1 is the actual value)
```

I would have expected `regionId` to be 1 prior to `attached` happening.   Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: I think the problem in your parent viewmodel, where `location.regionId` is `null` at the moment when `bind` in child viewmodel executed.

Comment: If the viewmodel is a component and the bindable field is propagated by the component's owning view in an asynchronous operation in its `bind` hook, it may happen, that `field` is "still" undefined in the component's `bind` hook. As far as I know the only hook where the completion is being awaited for, is the `activate` hook.

Answer (score 3):

The variable should be filled in the `bind()` phase.

If you add logging to each of the phases:

```
export class Child {
  @bindable()
  public field: string;

  constructor() {
    console.info("constructor: ", this.field);
  }

  bind() {
    console.info("bind: ", this.field);
  }

  attached() {
    console.info("attached: ", this.field);
  }
}
```

It produces the following log output:

```
constructor:  undefined
bind:  test
attached:  test
```

Where `test` is the value that I bound it to.

Comment: imo "the variable should be filled in the `bind()` phase" should rather be "the variable COULD be filled in the `bind()` phase". Again, if the owning viewmodel resolved the representation of `field` in a lengthy async operation in its `bind()` hook, it is very likely that `field` will be undefined in `Child`. If you want to ensure that the data resolved in a parent viewmodel is accessible in the `bind` hook of the children components, you need to resolve the data in `attached` hook of the parent view model.